# C++-style cast pointer to integer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, type-conversion

In the documentation for [GetQueuedCompletionStatus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), MSDN says

> This is done by specifying a valid event handle for the hEvent member
>   of the OVERLAPPED structure, and setting its low-order bit.

How do I do this with a C++-style cast, given that the event is of type HANDLE, a typedef of void *? I can't directly apply |= 1 to the pointer, reinterpret_cast converts between types with the same level of indirection only, and static_cast also doesn't work. What's the C++ way of doing this, avoiding C-style casts and using C++-style ones to convert to size_t? I know the alternative is to use a union but that seems even more of a hack than using C-style casts.

Comment: Reinterpret-cast works fine...

Comment: So you have a pointer which points to a data type other than an integer and you would like to cast this pointed to data into an int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

reinterpret_cast is what you need:

```
OVERLAPPED MyOverlapped;
// ...

MyOverlapped.hEvent = GetEvent();  // replace with whatever O/S call that is provided the event handle
ASSERT((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(MyOverlapped.hEvent) & 0x1) == 0x0);  // if lsbit is a flag, then OS source of hEvent better NOT have it INITIALLY set!
reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t &>(MyOverlapped.hEvent) |= 0x1;
// ...
GetQueuedCompletionStatus(..., &MyOverlapped, ...);
```

Comment: I believe if you want to use the result of `reinterpret_cast` as an lvalue you have to cast to reference `reinterpret_cast<unsigned int&>(MyOverlapped.hEvent) |= 0x1;`.

Comment: Casting to `unsigned int` (or `unsigned int&`) may not be ideal if the pointer is 64 bit... It's prefer to see `uintptr_t`...

Comment: Thanks, the casting to reference was the trick. Follow up: do I need to revert the LSB before doing CloseHandle() on the event??

Comment: @DisplayName, it definitely would not hurt to mask it back off, `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t &>(MyOverlapped.hEvent) &= ~static_cast<uintptr_t>(0x1)`, or better yet, save the original handle before the |= and use THAT in the Close()  :-D